# ORA-01843: not a valid month and ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table programer(IDNO NUMBER, PROJECTID VARCHAR(5),LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),HIRINGDATE DATE('MM-DD-YY') ,LANGUAGES VARCHAR(15),TASKNO INT,Privileges VARCHAR(25));
create table programer(IDNO NUMBER, PROJECTID VARCHAR(5),LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),HIRINGDATE DATE('MM-DD-YY') ,LANGUAGES VARCHAR(15),TASKNO INT,Privileges VARCHAR(25))
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(201,'NPR','GUPTA','SAURAV','01-01-95','VB',52,'SECRET');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMER VALUES(201,'NPR','GUPTA','SAURAV','01-05-95','VB',52,'SECRET')
Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: What is `DATE('MM-DD-YY')` ??

Comment: On a sidenote: From the error codes, we can see this is Oracle. I have added the tag for you. In Oracle use `VARCHAR2`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: And in general: Avoid two digit years. Is 95 supposed to be 1995 or 2095? Use four digit years instead for readability and in order to avoid making mistakes. Use ANSI date literals (`DATE '1995-01-01'`), not string literals.

Answer (score 2):

### ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The syntax error is probably here:

```
HIRINGDATE DATE('MM-DD-YY')
```

What is this supposed to mean? A date is a date. It consists of a day, a month and a year. So what is `'MM-DD-YY'` for?

Make this:

```
HIRINGDATE DATE
```

### ORA-01843: not a valid month

`'01-05-95'` is a string. The DBMS tries to interpret this and convert it into a date, which may or may not work depending on the regional settings you are using. Either name the format explicitely: `to_date('01-05-95', 'mm-dd-yy')`, or much better use ANSI date literals:

```
date '1995-01-05'
```